# Fix ssh line for Xpra bash script

Tags: bash, loops, ssh, ping

im writting a small script for starting an 'xpra' session with a remote machine. I'm pretty new to bash scripting, so I was wondering if someone could help me clean up the code a bit, concerning best practices.

The ssh line is the one i'm having problems with, as I must CTRL-C on the keyboard for the command to be killed and let it continue to *echo "done"*.

How can I fix that minor issue?

```
    ###                                         ###
    #       syntax: xpra.sh hostmachine command   #
    ##                                          ###

    ## Wake on LAN host machine.
    ~/scripts/$1

    ## Check if online and ssh command.
    ## Attach xpra client.
    while :; do
        ping -c 1 $1
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            ssh $1 "xpra start :7 && sleep 2 && ("DISPLAY=:7 $2"&) ";
            echo "done";
            sleep 5;
            echo "attaching";
            (xpra attach ssh:$1:7 &);
            break;
        else    
            echo "host offline";
            sleep 180s;
        fi
    done
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with xpra, but `ssh -f $COMMAND` will open an ssh session, ask for your credentials, then go into the background as it launches the command on the remote host.

Comment: thanks Adam Liss,
didn't realize ssh had a built-in option for that.
works beautifully!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as Adam Liss mentioned in the comments:

```
ssh -f $COMMAND
```

will open an ssh session, ask for your credentials, then go into the background as it launches the command on the remote host.

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions support starting remote sessions in one command, try:

```
xpra start ssh://HOST:SSH_PORT/DISPLAY --start-child=xterm
```

this will

- start a new remote session on display DISPLAY
- start an xterm in it
- then connect your client to this session

It's a lot cleaner than a script that relies on "sleep"...

Answer (score 0):

Either you want the ssh line to finish before moving to the next line, in which case what you have is correct; or you want to move on to the next line while it is still running, in which case you can append a "&" character to the line:

```
ssh $1 "xpra start :7 && sleep 2 && ("DISPLAY=:7 $2"&) " &
```

(Main comment I would make about your style is that ending all your lines with ";"'s is unnecessary, and it would be clearer if you indented the parts of your `if` statement.)

Comment: The `&` will put `ssh` in the background _before_ it asks for your credentials, which is probably not what you want. See my comment about the `-f` option.

Comment: Also, you should really use the "--start=app" switch, otherwise the environment for the app will not be optimal for running in xpra.